# Catch-all rewrite rule for apache that doesn't cause duplicate urls from .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

You can make a catch-all rewrite rule for apache that acts somewhat like an alias, but can be implemented in a `.htaccess` file while an alias can't.

As an example, assuming your document root is a hierarchy like this:

```
/.htaccess
/test/
/test/.htaccess
/test/file
```

You can "Alias" all requests to the test folder by making the root `.htaccess` contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

And the second `.htaccess` contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This works great, and usually is all you need. It just has one problem - it creates multiple valid urls. Now you can access the file with both `/file` and `/test/file`.

Ordinarily this isn't a problem, but if you add a file called `/test/test` you'll see the problem, as the fake alias stops working entirely. If the subfolder has a complex `.htaccess` of its own it can cause major headaches.

Is there any way to fake an alias from a `.htaccess` without the original urls still working? (Any `RewriteCond` for the subfolder that would check if we've already been rewritten or not?)

Comment: What is the reason behind the requirement to use htaccess?

Comment: Because if I could change the virtualhost to make an alias, I'd just change the documentroot. In production of course this makes little difference, but it's helpful for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but if you add a file called `/test/test` you'll see the problem, as the fake alias stops working entirely.

Yes, the second `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory prevents the URL being rewritten (since mod-rewrite is not inherited by default). You could get around this by just having the one `.htaccess` file in the document root that rewrites all requests that have not already been rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /test/$1 [L]
```

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request and set to `200` (OK) after the first successful rewrite.

However, if you still *need* a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory (for other mod_rewrite directives) then you'll either need to:

- repeat these directives in the subdirectories `.htaccess` file. (You then wouldn't strictly need the above `RewriteCond` directive in the parent `.htaccess` file.)
- Or, enable mod_rewrite inheritance. But I think you'd struggle on Apache 2.2. You would probably need something like `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` (in the subdirectories `.htaccess` file), which is only available on Apache 2.4.

> It just has one problem - it creates multiple valid urls.

The above method resolves this issue as well, since all requests are now rewritten (which is more like how an Apache `Alias` would behave in the server config).

---

Otherwise, you would need to ensure that the base subdirectory was unique in order to be able to implement a canonical redirect back to the document root if the base subdirectory was accessed directly. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /unique-subdir
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` holds the first line of the *initial* request header and does not change when the request is rewritten.

Comment: Except now it's broken if you have a file `/test/test/test` which you *do* want to access from url `/test/test`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, just realised what your saying! (Whenever I've needed something like this I've always ensured the base subdirectory was unique in order to avoid such problems.) I've _rewritten_ my answer.

Comment: I'm too tired to think right now - but I'll tick your answer since you obviously know more about it than me :)